# Kafka + Spring Boot + Consumer Messages are missed what app is restarted

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a simple Kafka Spring Boot consumer with one topic, 3 partitions and 1 consumer.
once messages are read, it is processed and committed back.

When application is stopped/started, the message which was just read but not committed yet is skipped in the next run. I was expecting the message not committed to be read again after restart.

for example,

**run 1**

1. offset 1 consumed and committed
2. offset 2 consumed and committed
3. offset 3 consumed

**run 2**

4. offset 4 consumed and committed

if you see the pattern, I was expecting offset 3 as its not committed yet in run2 but it skips 3 and reads 4 instead

Please find the code snippet

1. kafka config - `enable.auto.commit=false`
2. Set props - `props.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE)`

consumer/listener:

```
public void consume(@Payload String message, @Header int partition, @Header int offsets, @Heaader String value, Acknowledgement acknowledgement) {

    process(message);

    acknowledgement.acknowledge();

}
```

kafka picks always the next offset though it never committed if stop and restart. i tried with commitSync as well but same behaviour. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64461894/kafka-offset-increments-even-without-reaching-ack . Short answer you ack the message with offset 4, so for kafka you have read all the previous messages.

Comment: thanks. i will go through it

Comment: @MissingSemiColon that question is not the same as this one and its answer is not really relevant. It concerns situations where failing to ack means the same offset is not tried again in the same application run. But the current question is different, it concerns failing to retry the same offset after a restart. And after a restart, it's the _committed_ offset that matters.

Comment: True its not the same case sorry. Then maybe a bit more information is required, I would check if your configuration is working. Remove the ack and check that it is not moving your committed offset. Because it is true that if you ack message 2 and restarted you should see message 3. Also try to use MANUAL instead of MANUAL_IMMEDIATE https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.AckMode.html